# Power BI - New rows with inhereted values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

got table

| Period | Entity | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NOV 2020 | Entity 1 | 20 |
| DEC 2020 | Entity 1 | 30 |
| JAN 2021 | Entity 1 | 25 |

Now I want to insert row for every period with same value but different entity, so my table looks like this:

| Period | Entity | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NOV 2020 | Entity 1 | 20 |
| NOV 2020 | Entity 2 | 20 |
| DEC 2020 | Entity 1 | 30 |
| DEC 2020 | Entity 2 | 30 |
| JAN 2021 | Entity 1 | 25 |
| JAN 2021 | Entity 2 | 25 |

Is it something I have to do in query editor through new custom column? Or just through new measure after data load?

Basically what I really need is to present in visual "Entity 2" with same values as "Entity 1"  for multiple preiods.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: In one table have all the entities listed. Then do a full outer join

Answer (score 0):

Follow these below steps in **Power Query Editor**-

**Step-1:** Duplicate your base table.

**Step-2:** Replace value "Entity 1" with "Entity 2" in the **Entity** column of your new table.

**Step-3:** Now select **Append Query as Ne** option from the ribbon and select both old and new table.

Finally you will find the below output in your newly created/appended table-

[image]